# RPG style sprite movement with SDL2 using Crystal

Tags: sdl-2, 2d-games, crystal-lang

I'm using [SDL2 with Crystal](https://github.com/ysbaddaden/sdl.cr) to make a 16bit RPG style tile-based game. I've seen this question asked a ton, but even with all the answers I've come across, I'm still not getting the movement I'm looking for. Have you ever played Final Fantasy IV, V, or VI on the SNES? I'm looking for movement like that. No diagonal, character is always over a tile, and never stops between 2 tiles.

```
# main game loop
loop do
  ticks = Time.monotonic.milliseconds / 1000.0
  case event = SDL::Event.poll
  when SDL::Event::Keyboard
    case event.sym
    when .right?
      character.move_right(ticks)
    end
  end

  character.draw(renderer)
  renderer.present
  #other code handling break and stuff omitted
end

# character.cr
VELOCITY = 100
def move_right(delta_ticks)
  @direction_facing = "east"
  @x += VELOCITY * delta_ticks
end

def draw(renderer)
  sprite = @directions[@direction_facing]
  renderer.copy(sprite, dstrect: SDL::Rect[@x.to_i, @y.to_i, 64, 64])
end
```

The way my current movement works, the character starts walking slow, then picks up speed then drops back down to walking slow like it's shifting gears or something. I know my line `@x += VELOCITY * delta_ticks` is wrong, but I wasn't able to find one that worked how I wanted. This also doesn't take in to account stopping directly over a tile (in this case 64x64).

**EDIT:** I've tried to transpose the suggestion @genpfault gave. It still doesn't do what I want, but since I don't know C++, I may have missed some stuff. That code update is [here](https://gist.github.com/jwoertink/77795fbc89a76dc2bd0ffac797deb738)

Answer (score 1):

- Make a little "tasklet" helper (I know *zero* about Crystal; in C++ I'd just have this be a class/struct with member data & functions) that encapsulates the character's current tile x/y position (and fine, sub-tile x/y position)
- When you handle the left/right/up/down input, check if a current tasklet is still doing its thing; if not, make a new tasklet with the desired direction
- Each frame while a tasklet is active, process it: increment/decrement (1px/frame? up to you) the character's fine x/y position until it hits the goal tile position; if the tasklet hits the goal position this frame, remove it (and update the character's tile position)

This way you prevent new input from interfering with character motion while it's in progress, as well as smoothly animating tile transitions.

Something like this:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <memory>

struct Character
{
    int m_TileX;
    int m_TileY;
    int m_FineX; // in 16ths of a tile
    int m_FineY; // in 16ths of a tile
};

class ITask
{
public:
    virtual ~ITask() {};

    // override & return true to indicate this task is done
    virtual bool Run() = 0;
};

class CharacterAnimator : public ITask
{
public:
    CharacterAnimator( Character& c, int dx, int dy )
        : m_C( c )
        , m_Dx( dx )
        , m_Dy( dy )
    {}

    ~CharacterAnimator() override {}

    bool Run() override
    {
        m_C.m_FineX += m_Dx;
        m_C.m_FineY += m_Dy;
        bool done = false;
        if( m_C.m_FineX <= -16 ) { m_C.m_TileX--; m_C.m_FineX = 0; done = true; }
        if( m_C.m_FineY <= -16 ) { m_C.m_TileY--; m_C.m_FineY = 0; done = true; }
        if( m_C.m_FineX >= 16 )  { m_C.m_TileX++; m_C.m_FineX = 0; done = true; }
        if( m_C.m_FineY >= 16 )  { m_C.m_TileY++; m_C.m_FineY = 0; done = true; }
        return done;
    }

private:
    Character& m_C;
    int m_Dx;
    int m_Dy;
};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow
        (
        "SDL2", 
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
        640, 480, 
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
        );
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer
        (
        window,
        0,
        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC
        );
    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize( renderer, 320, 240 );

    Character c;
    c.m_TileX = 9;
    c.m_TileY = 7;
    c.m_FineX = 0;
    c.m_FineY = 0;

    std::unique_ptr< ITask > movementTask;

    bool running = true;
    while( running )
    {
        if( movementTask && movementTask->Run() )
        {
            movementTask.reset();
        }

        SDL_Event ev;
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &ev ) )
        {
            if ( ev.type == SDL_QUIT )
                running = false;
            if( ev.type == SDL_KEYUP && ev.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE )
                running = false;
            if( ev.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && ev.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_UP    && !movementTask )
                movementTask = std::unique_ptr< ITask >( new CharacterAnimator( c,  0, -1 ) );
            if( ev.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && ev.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN  && !movementTask )
                movementTask = std::unique_ptr< ITask >( new CharacterAnimator( c,  0,  1 ) );
            if( ev.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && ev.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LEFT  && !movementTask )
                movementTask = std::unique_ptr< ITask >( new CharacterAnimator( c, -1,  0 ) );
            if( ev.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && ev.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RIGHT && !movementTask )
                movementTask = std::unique_ptr< ITask >( new CharacterAnimator( c,  1,  0 ) );
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 );
        SDL_RenderClear( renderer );

        // draw character
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255 );
        SDL_Rect r =
        {
            c.m_TileX * 16 + c.m_FineX,
            c.m_TileY * 16 + c.m_FineY,
            16,
            16
        };
        SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &r );

        SDL_RenderPresent( renderer );
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer( renderer );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I sort of follow what you're saying. Not 100% clear, but I think I get where you're going. Do you have a C++ example? I could try to transpose from that.

Comment: @jeremywoertink: Edited.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the code sample! I don't actually know C++, so I'll take some time to digest this, and then report back.

Comment: After a bit of study, I still don't have it, but I understand your code a bit more. One thing I'm confused on is where the `movementTask.reset();` comes from. I don't see a reset function defined, so I'm not really sure what it is that it's resetting.

Comment: @jeremywoertink: That's a [`std::unique_ptr` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) that [sets the pointer to NULL and deletes the object that's pointed-to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#unique_ptr).  Sort of a "Get rid of it, I don't care about this object any more." type of deal.  Smart pointers like that in C++ let you be a bit more cavalier about memory management since the various destructors will take care of deleting things as objects go out of scope.

Comment: Ah, so I could just set that to nil then. Well, I tried to re-create your example the best I could. It moves 1px by 1px very VERY slowly while holding down the arrow key. I'm not sure what I'm missing.